# Packing data into a buffer portably

Tags: c++

I have to place several integer values into a (32 byte) buffer, where each integer must be at a specific place in the buffer (I'm going to use the data in OpenGL VBOs).

The way I'm doing it now is kind of ugly. All the content is supposed to be placed at the address buf2. Don't bother looking at the values I'm assigning to the buffer, as those are irrelevant to the problem.

```
    uint32_t *const coords      = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(buf2 + CoordDataOff);
    uint16_t *const texcoords   = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(buf2 + TcoordDataOff);
    uint32_t *const color       = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(buf2 + ColorDataOff);

    coords[0] = x + bearing[0]; // left
    coords[1] = y + bearing[1] - 64*(tcoords[3] - tcoords[1]); // bottom
    coords[2] = x + bearing[0] + 64*(tcoords[2] - tcoords[0]); // right
    coords[3] = y + bearing[1]; // top
    copy_n(tcoords, 4, texcoords);
    *color = c.color;
```

Is there any nicer, portable way of accomplishing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your buffer just contain this data for each vertex? You could just generate a struct

```
struct TData
{
  uint32_t coords[4];
  uint16_t texcoords[4];
  uint32_t color;
};
```

then it would be as simple as treating your buffer as an array of TData

```
TData verts[100];
vert[0].coord[0] = x;
vert[0].coord[1] = y;
...
FunctionToWriteToBuffer((void *)verts, sizeof(TData) * 100);
```

or in the code you have above

```
  TData *vert = (TData *)buf2;
```

That should also make things easier to read to maintain

Comment: Your `struct` will likely insert 2 bytes of padding before or after `texcoords`. The C++ standard doesn't specify where. You could explicitly add the padding, but given the OP's unspecified memory limits, it might not work.

Comment: sorry yes, I was thinking about #pragma pack() as i was typing the answer, but forgot to include it. It is very important that you do this. The last line of code I pasted should be ok for the use in the question (depending on the values of CoordDataOff, TcoordDataOff, ColorDataOff). But I guess there is some similar code that will populate the VBO. Using the same struct for reading and writing to the buffer should keep things easier.

Comment: pragma pack will cause misalignment for color field, this might cause data abort on ARM processor when accessing such variable. Instead of using single struct, maybe keep each type coords,tex,color in separate arrays and bind then with OGL

Comment: @luskan Having each attribute type would be very inconvenient due to other parts of my code, so that is not an option. I'd rather keep my current way.

Comment: If I understand your current solution correctly, then it can still cause Data Aborts on ARM. If number of texcoords entries in your large buffer is odd, then color entries will start at misaligned address.

Comment: But the number of texcoord entries isn't odd, there are 4 entries. Though I could place the color before the texcoords, if that would help somehow.

Comment: right - then it should be OK, I suppose placing color before textcorrds is a good idea